# How to set a filter on a router that will check whether the user is subscribed to a telegram channel and returns True if subscribed, else False

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

In the file 'services', i have function:

```py
async def user_in_channel(bot: Bot, user_id):
    in_channel = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@godblessusalll', user_id=user_id)
    return in_channel.status != 'left'
```

I also have a file 'user_handlers', that contains all the handlers. I want to set a filter on router, to check the subsricbition, like:

```py
router.message.filter(user_in_channel(bot=bot, user_id=??))
```

BUT, how can I replace the user_id parameter with its id if I don’t have it?
I dont have database,